# Margin set programmatically on RadioButton not applied

Tags: android, margin

I'm trying to set a margin to RadioButtons added programmatically to a RadioGroup, but it fails.: the RadioButtons are correctly added, but they have 0 margin...

Anybody can help?

[image]

**layout**

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rg_nav" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RadioGroup>
```

**activity**

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

rg_nav = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_nav);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_rb = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        (int)(8*density),
        (int)(8*density));
int margin = (int)(6*density);
params_rb.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);

for(String url : product.list_url_pic){

    RadioButton radio_btn = new RadioButton(ProductHome.this);  
    radio_btn.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.rb_nav);
    radio_btn.setId(rb_id++);
    rg_nav.addView(radio_btn, params_rb);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had to replace

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_rb = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    (int)(8*density),
    (int)(8*density));
```

by

```
RadioGroup.LayoutParams params_rb = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                (int)(8*density),
                (int)(8*density));
```

Comment: It is important to us radiobutton's parent view to generate LayoutParams. Thanks.

Comment: what is density ? @jul

Comment: @Erum Check the question, it is defined there.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams rg_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f);
RadioGroup radio_group=new RadioGroup(this);
radio_group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
radio_group.setLayoutParams(rg_params);

RadioButton dry=new RadioButton(this);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams params_soiled = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(getBaseContext(), null);
params_soiled.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
dry.setLayoutParams(button_params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct.
Try applying `LayoutParams` directly to your buttons

```
radio_btn.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.rb_nav);
radio_btn.setId(rb_id++);    
rg_nav.addView(radio_btn);
radio_btn.setLayoutParams(params_rb);
```

Comment: @jul try checking that `margin` is not `0`: `Log.d("whatever", "margin value: " + margin);`